# Remove unwanted characters from string with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

This Meteor server code using cheerio to extract text from html:

` const myLines = ResObj.$('.panel-body').text();

Which console.log the following:[image]

Using regex, how can I get only non-empty lines, like:

He is
not happy today
and needs to eay
select

I have tried few things for no avail, like `replace(/(\W\r\n)/, "")` and so on...

Comment: You have to precise, do you want the break-lines `(\n)` to stay or not? They are in your desired output while you are getting rid of them in your regex.

Comment: Yes, a line break at the end of each non-empty line. but remove all empty lines.

Comment: Why use regex vs native js string.split w/ .indexOf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```js
myLines = '\r\n          \r\n      He is\r\n \r\n \r\n not happy today\r\n   \r\n   ';
myLines = myLines.replace(/\s*?(^|\n)\s*/g, '$1'); 
console.log(myLines);
```